# Open a terminal window in another screen on login

Tags: terminal, macos

I was wondering if there is a way to get a terminal window to open up in another screen on startup. I know you can set terminal to open on start up, but I specifically want it to open in another screen.

I have Mac OS X 10.11.1

Answer (score 1):

You can write an AppleScript with the following statements:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    set position of first window of application process "Terminal" to {X_VALUE, Y_VALUE}
end tell
```

The first one launch the Terminal while the second one moves its window to the defined coordinates. Export the AppleScript as application and make it run automatically at startup.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Window Group** to save the configuration and layout of one or more windows to recreate them again later, and you can tell Terminal to open a specific window group at startup.

To create a window group, arrange terminal window(s), then choose **Window > Save Windows as Group**. While creating a group, you can select the “Use window group when Terminal starts” checkbox to update the Startup preference (see below).

To open a window group when opening Terminal, set

> Preferences > General > On startup, open

to “Window group” and use the popup menu to choose the group you want to open (or you can set this while creating a group, as mentioned above).

Note that if you have the system **Resume** feature enabled, this preference only takes effect when Terminal has no windows already open. Also, if you're unaware of **Resume**: you can enable it and then Terminal will automatically restore any windows that were open when you quit it. You can enable Resume by unselecting

> System Preferences > General > Close windows when quitting an app

to restore open windows when reopening applications. You can also invert this behavior on an application-by-application basis by pressing the Option <kbd>⌥</kbd> modifier key when quitting an application to either close or not close the windows.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood the question.
My answer would be: go to the dock at the bottom of the screen, select the icon of the terminal, ctrl-click and keep the fingers on the keys! and a menu pops-up, chose option, then "show desktop 3"